# Paypal's Token ID Unique?

Tags: php, paypal

Is the paypal's `Token ID` which it returns (ie: `EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`), always unique? i am doubting it would be? But what i am doing is that i am inserting it to my transaction table to verify if this transaction has already been processed.

I know Transaction ID can work too, but the thing is that the Token ID is returned first before even using the PayPal API methods such as `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` or `DoExpressCheckout`.

Please let me know what you think is best, from your own experiences.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the Transaction ID to identify the transaction.  Just from the name, the Token is probably a nonce used for security, and is not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Token is unique, but it only represents the session, which is why it is returned first. It does not indicate a complete transaction at all, and you shouldn't store it for that purpose. I would not recommend storing it for future use anyway, because PayPal doesn't use it to identify the transaction for refunds, etc (that I've seen at least).

I recommend you only use the Token to manage the actual checkout flow going from `SetExpressCheckout  -> GetExpressCheckoutDetails -> DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, and then store the TransactionID returned from `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` as your "transaction complete" indicator. You should probably check the `PaymentStatus` return, too, since eChecks do not give the money to your account right away.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i thought pretty similar. The reason i was using was so i could block multiple refresh attempts, do you think that is a good idea?

Comment: `for example:` The user just clicked the confirm button and in the next page his reservation was a success, and his reservation and transaction information is stored successfully. But if the user refreshes the page it would cause some errors such as Duplicate Transaction ID error as i have the column set with a Unique index in mysql. It would still insert the reservation data as its primary key is a unique reservation code generated at that time of inserting the reservation data into MySQL.

Comment: I think i just realized it isn't a good idea to do this, in my case above too. So thanks for clearing the confusion for me.

Comment: Glad I could help! Btw, if your user refreshes the page and you resubmit the request in full, PayPal is going to return an error because the completed session Token is now invalid. Consequently, the TransactionID will be empty.

Comment: I have tried this numerous times but consequently sending the same token id to Paypal still shows the same response (including the transaction id), the only difference appears to be is that it doesn't deduct the amount from the user more than once.

Comment: At first i was thinking the only good solution could be to redirect the user once more after processing and show the result there, but it would be another page to load which i wanted to avoid just to show the results, Do you think the is the best way?

Comment: sorry the previous message was sent before i had the chance to complete it, but i also found another solution which was to create a session variable something like `checkoutStatus` and when everything is processed i set its value to something like `checked-out`? but i'm not sure which would be the best approach to do the redirect or this? or maybe both `combined`?

Comment: I would do the redirect. The redirect would be near instant anyway, and the session variable would tend to lock people out of starting a new purchase immediately after another. There's really many ways to do it. As long as PayPal is preventing duplicate charges, I think you'll be fine. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction ID is unique for transaction.
Token ID is a number that created for check if is correct the Transaction ID.